# how install postgres (for rails) on vagrant so "vagrant" role does not have to be manually created?

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

How can I install postgres under vagrant so it runs in development mode the same as running postgres.app... with no user or password required?

Moving my Rails 3.2.21 development environment over to vagrant, if I leave my database.yml file as-is, I get the error `FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist` when I run `rake db:create`

If modify `config/database.yml` by adding

```
username: postgres
password: postgres
```

it works. But that "breaks" the database connection for any developer not using vagrant (becasue using postgres.app on a development machine does not use a user or password). And I want to be abel to run `vagrant up` without having to manually create a postgres user using psql each and every time.

Is there, for example, a way to have a **vagrant-specific database.yml** that gets used only when running rake and rails under vagrant?